# Select a section out of the middle of a list in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list in C#.  Given two number - the starting position and the number of records - how can I select from the middle of a list? What kind of collection should I use?

E.g.  Starting position = 10.  Number of records = 20.  Total number of records in list = 50. I want to get back the objects in elements 10 to 29.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming you're using .NET 3.5:

```
using System.Linq;

list.Skip(10).Take(20)
```

Comment: @Jason: Joe is correct.  I counted it up on my fingers to be sure :)  Off-by-one strikes again

Comment: @Jason Its inclusive of the end elements so gotta be 20 and he also says `Number of Records = 20`

Answer (score 2):

Something like `list1.Skip(10).Take(20)` should work for you

Answer (score 1):

use the LINQ extension methods `skip()` and `take()`

```
var myList = getList();
var middle = myList.Skip(10).Take(20);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
List<T>
```

with the LINQ extension methods mentioned by others (with "using System.Linq").